# Avoid event.preventDefault() boilerplate in backbone event handlers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a lot of Backbone.js actions that start with link like:

```
<a href="#makeCookies">Make Cookies</a>
```

and a `Backbone.View` events hash like:

```
'click [href=#makeCookies]': 'makeCookies'
```

and an event handler function like:

```
makeCookies: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //code to make cookies
    //I have no intention of ever using #makeCookies in the URL,
    //it's just there so I can wire up the event handler properly
}
```

Is there a clean way to avoid that boilerplate `event.preventDefault()`. I thought about just using `<button>` tags instead of `<a>` tags but that seemed inappropriate.

Comment: I actually think that `<button>` is more appropriate than `<a>` for anything that you can press but doesn't naturally take you to a separate page: if pressing a thing doesn't change the URL then that thing isn't an `<a>` at all. `<button>` also has the great advantage of having a `disabled` attribute. Just make sure you say `<button type="button">` to avoid different browsers assuming different defaults for the `type` attribute.

Comment: +1 for the use of button

Comment: That's probably the way to go I guess. My 2.5 annoyances with that are `<button type="button" class="makeCookies">` is almost as much boilerplate as `event.preventDefault()`, then if I want it to just be a text link I have to style it the opposite of its default styling. What do folks think about just using `<span class="makeCookies">Make Cookies</span>`?

Comment: The idea of using `<a>`s is that crawlers can follow the `href`s when they parse your page even if they don't 'speak' javascript. Of course if your app is not public or if you're not taking steps (such as server-side rendering) to deliver the rendered pages to the crawler in the first place, then there's really no reason to stick to `<a>`s.

Comment: Well, links that navigate to other resources can have hrefs and do the preventDefault thing when running in a browser but still be useful for crawlers, but the "Sign In" link that doesn't change the URL and just pops up a sign in dialog doesn't need an href.

Comment: For a while now I've thought that it might be useful to have event.preventDefault() called for all click actions bound using the events hash. I reckon that in 99% of cases when you're binding a click handler, you want to prevent default behaviour.

Comment: I agree buttons make more sense when it comes to symantics but you always end up with killing the default button styles like border, padding, outline and background

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you need to have the href attribute at all, if you plan on discarding it anyway? How about just using a class name?

HTML code:

```
<a class="makeCookies">Make Cookies</a>
```

View code:

```
'click .makeCookies': 'makeCookies'
...
makeCookies: function (event) {
    // No need for event.preventDefault() anymore!
}
```

Comment: That might work pretty well. Gotta manually add the cursor: pointer style it seems as the browser seems to only do that if it has an href attribute.

Comment: Yeah. I've never understood why browsers do that.

Comment: Set `href` equal to `javascript:void(0);`. This will give you the cursor and keeps the `a` as a link.

Comment: If you are concerned with pages reporting "Content-Security-Policy" (CSP) avoid the "javascript:" links.  They may also violate http/https strictness.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy

Answer (score -1):

You could add a prevent-default handler to the document element. Like so:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }  
})
```

This would of course disable all navigation initiated by a-tags but if your app provides custom handling for that then it shouldn't be a problem.

If you'd like to let some a-tags 'pass through' then you could add further conditions in the prevent-default handler, like checking if the value of the href attribute begins with '#'.

Comment: This is me, many years after posting this answer. Since then, it seems like it's been downvoted a few times. Mysteriously. As in, there's no comment offering any sort of explanation of why this is not an appropriate answer. Maybe it isn't, but I (and everyone else) have no way of knowing. Which is quite counter-productive and not helpful to anyone. I would appreciate any future downvoters to be helpful by offering a short rationale. Cheers :)